# Beginner in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, computer-vision

I have excel sheet, where 3 column x1, x2 , x3 are present. x1,x2  have question and x3 have all the answer serially, I mean x1 and x2 1st row have question and that questions answer is x3 1st column. x1, and x2 have mixture of numerical and text data and have some NA value is also there.

Here my work is I have to using NLP technics to solve these issue, if I type x1 and x2 questions it will give x3 answer . so the question is not given full statement but some selected words, if I will give some selected keyword also it will be answer. Please guide me where and how I need to start . Please guide and sugest

Comment: I don't understand your question... could you post a screenshot of this excel sheet??  And you should add the code you have used. And an example of what you want to achieve would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds (your question is a bit unclear) that you have a bunch of mixed data types, and you only want to process x1 = some text1 + x2 = some text2 -> x3 = some answer text. 
I would recommend first cleaning up your data, you can easily remove NA's or NAN's by piping your data into a PANDAS dataframe (I'm unsure what language you're using either). If you're using python, you can also easily remove the numeric information by using the is.digit function. 
I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, so I can't really recommend things to do after cleaning your data. Posting 2 examples of a proper and improper x1, x2 and x3 might be helpful.